# How to set value in dropdown that already been populated by mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

i want to set value in bootstrap modal dropdown using jquery, that dropdown is also populated by mysql database, and when i select the any value from data table, model open and that selected value should already placed is modal drop down.picking up the value by jquery `closest()` function

> this is where im getting the value of `b_name`

```
<td class="p_brand_name">Apple</td>
```

> here is my Modal Code.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="field-2" class="control-label">Brand</label> 
      <select class="form-control" name="p_brand_name" id="p_brand_name">
         <option>Select Brand</option>
         <option value="1">Apple</option>
         <option value="2">Sony</option>
         <option value="3">huawei</option>
         <option value="4">Toshiba</option>
         <option value="5">Dell</option>
         <option value="6">Hp</option>
         <option value="7">Samsung</option>
         <option value="8">LG</option>
         <option value="9">Aspire</option>
         <option value="10">Lenovo</option>
         <option value="11">Oppo</option>
         <option value="14">Vivo</option>
         <option value="16">Dawlance</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

> Here is my jquery code

```
  var $row = $(this).closest('tr');

 var b_name = $row.find('.p_brand_name').text();  // e.g it has value apple (b_name = apple)
        console.log(p_id,b_name);
        // $('select option[value='+b_name+']').prop({defaultSelected: true});
        // $('#p_brand_name').val(b_name).attr('selected', 'selected');
        // $('#p_sct_name').find($row.find('.p_sct_name').text()).attr('selected', 'selected');
        // $('#p_color_name select').attr('value',$row.find('.p_color_name').text());
        // $("#p_brand_name").val("b_name");
        // $("#p_brand_name").get(0).selectedIndex = b_name;
        // $("#p_brand_name").val(b_name).change();
         // $("#p_brand_name")[b_name].selectedIndex=b_name;
        // $('#p_brand_name').val(b_name).attr("selected", "selected");
        // $('#p_brand_name').val(b_name).trigger("chosen:updated");
```

i have tried these all but none of this work

Comment: You're looking for `.find('.p_brand_name')` but there is no select element with that classname. Change  `id="p_brand_name"` to `class="p_brand_name"`

Comment: b_name has the value already, i want that value in dropdown.

Comment: So `b_name` is the text description of an `option` and not it's `value` right?

Comment: `b_name` is the variable in which selected value is store. so i want that value to be set in bootstrap modal dropdown.

Comment: any suggestion ?

Comment: If that console log is working then `$('#p_brand_name').val(b_name)` should work. Assumes there is an  `<option>` value that has a match

Comment: yes console.log() is working.and yes it has the value that match. but its not working

Comment: Then provide an html only [mcve] that demonstrates issue.

Comment: Also make sure no whitespace at ends of that `b_name` string

Comment: no white_space, and i tried to edit my question. and everything that is related i think i have provided, if there is anything else please let me know

Comment: Can you demonstrate actual values rather than php tags?

Comment: i have change the php tags with actual values.

Answer (score 1):

first of all i have demonstrated here how to get the option value and text on the change event of the select box:

```js
$(document).ready( function(){

    $('.form-control').on('change', function() {

        let option_value = $(this).val();
        let option_text = $(this).children("option:selected").text();
        console.log(option_value, option_text);
    });


 });
```

Now, if i understand you correct, i hope, you want to file the select box like you have selected the option your self, well: in PHP you can do this like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>StackOverFlow</title>

    <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
            crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<td class="p_brand_name">Apple</td>
<?php
$select_box_options = ['1' => 'Apple', '2' => 'Sony', '3' => 'huawei'];
?>
<form>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="field-2" class="control-label">Brand</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="p_brand_name" id="p_brand_name">
                <option>Select Brand</option>
                <?php
                    foreach ($select_box_options as $value => $text) {
                        $selected = ($text === 'Apple') ? 'selected' : '';
                ?>
                        <option value="<?=$value?>" <?=$selected?>><?=$text?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and in JQuery to fire event:

```js
 $('.form-control').val('2').trigger('change');
```